# How to retrieve bold, italic and underlined words from plain text and surround them by HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, algorithm

**What I want to achieve:**

**Input:** (Input text comes from a Excel cell)

This is a **string** includes **bold**, *italic* and underlined words.

**Expected output:**

```
This is a <b>string</b> includes <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i> and <u>underlined</u> words.
```

**What I tried:** (This method iterates the plain text by characters not words.)

```
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder fontText = new StringBuilder();
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test.xls");
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
        //Read the first cell
        Range cell = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1];
          for (int index = 1; index <= cell.Text.ToString().Length; index++)
            {
              //cell here is a Range object
              Characters ch = cell.get_Characters(index, 1);
              bool bold = (bool) ch.Font.Bold;
              if(bold){
                 if (html.Length == 0)
                      html.Append("<b>");
                 html.Append(ch.Text);
           }
      }
      if (html.Length !=0) html.Append("</b>")
```

But this method returns all bold texts surrounded by HTML tags like `<b>stringbold</b>`

Expected result is: `<b>string</b>` and `<b>bold</b>`

**Any great thoughts on this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. From the code it looks like VBA or something. What is a cell/range object? Consider using an XML library to build the HTML string, it might make life easier.

Comment: Also, `<u>` denotes underlined text. `<a>` is the anchor tag.

Comment: What is `cell`?

Comment: You should put a closing /b as soon in an `else` statement, so as soon as the bold is false, you close the tag. You may need another variable to track where you're at in the string.

Comment: @Charlie Sorry i missed something for sure. 'cell` is the `Excel` cell. Plain text comes from Excel cell and I can only iterate the text by characters using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Comment: @BrianRogers Sorry i missed something for sure. 'cell` is the `Excel` cell. Plain text comes from Excel cell and I can only iterate the text by characters using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes you are right. But actually underline stands for a link.

Comment: @Charlie Yes it is `Range` object.

Comment: This just seems to be a bad algorithm. You are only ever checking for bold, and as @Rufus says, you aren't properly closing the tags.

Comment: @Charlie Before In order to add proper tags need to know bold texts right? The code above either achieves get all bold texts or surround them by proper tags.But now the problem is, how to separate the bold text word by word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took half of my day to figure out this solution.

> 1.The code works with **Bold**,*Italic* and underline characters.
>
> 2.The algorithm is little bit complicated. If any optimization available or anyone come up with better solution, please post new
>   answer.

**`ExcelReader` method:**

```
public string ExcelReader(string excelFilePath)
    {
        StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder();
        //string excelFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Test.xls");
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
        Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
        //Read the first cell
        Range cell = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1];

        //Check if one bold or italic WORD.
        bool IfStop = false;
        //Check if character is the start of bold or italic character.
        bool ifFirstSpecialCharacter = true;
        //Initialize a empty tag
        string tag = "";
        //Check if it is the last index
        bool isLastIndex = false;
        for (int index = 1; index <= cell.Text.ToString().Length; index++)
        {
            //Check if the current character is bold or italic
            bool IfSpecialType = false;
            //cell here is a Range object
            Characters ch = cell.get_Characters(index, 1);
            XlUnderlineStyle temp = (XlUnderlineStyle)ch.Font.Underline;
            bool underline = false;

            if (temp == XlUnderlineStyle.xlUnderlineStyleSingle)
                underline = true;

            bool bold = (bool)ch.Font.Bold;
            bool italic = (bool)ch.Font.Italic;

            if (underline)
            {
                if (tag != "" && tag != "<u>")
                {
                    resultText.Append(tag.Insert(1, "/"));
                    ifFirstSpecialCharacter = true;
                    IfStop = true;
                }
                tag = "<u>";
                IfSpecialType = true;
            }
            if (bold)
            {
                if (tag != "" && tag != "<b>")
                {
                    resultText.Append(tag.Insert(1, "/"));
                    ifFirstSpecialCharacter = true;
                    IfStop = true;
                }
                tag = "<b>";
                IfSpecialType = true;
            }
            if (italic)
            {
                if (tag != "" && tag != "<i>")
                {
                    resultText.Append(tag.Insert(1, "/"));
                    ifFirstSpecialCharacter = true;
                    IfStop = true;
                }
                tag = "<i>";
                IfSpecialType = true;
            }
            if (index == cell.Text.ToString().Length)
                isLastIndex = true;
            DetectSpecialCharracterByType(isLastIndex, resultText, ref tag, IfSpecialType, ref IfStop, ref ifFirstSpecialCharacter, ch);
        }
        wb.Close();
        return resultText.ToString();
    }
```

**`DetectSpecialCharacterByType` method:**

```
private static void DetectSpecialCharacterByType(bool isLastIndex, StringBuilder fontText, ref string tag, bool ifSpecialType, ref bool IfStop, ref bool ifFirstSpecialCharacter, Characters ch)
    {
        if (ifSpecialType)
        {
            //If it is the first character of the word, put the <b> or <i> at the beginning.
            if (ifFirstSpecialCharacter)
            {
                fontText.Append(tag);
                ifFirstSpecialCharacter = false;
                IfStop = false;
            }
            //This is a edge case.If the last word of the text is bold or italic, put the </b> or </i>
            if (isLastIndex)
            {
                fontText.Append(ch.Text);
                fontText.Append(tag.Insert(1, "/"));
            }
            else
                fontText.Append(ch.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            //If it is the last character of one word, add </b> or </i> at the end.
            if (!IfStop && tag != "")
            {
                fontText.Append(tag.Insert(1, "/"));
                IfStop = true;
                ifFirstSpecialCharacter = true;
                tag = "";
            }
            fontText.Append(ch.Text);
        }
    }
```

> Code perfectly works by simply copy pasting and adding new reference
>   `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do:

1. Create a helper class that knows about Font styles, and their opening and closing tags, and which can keep track of the "current" font style
2. Start out the class with Regular style, and then in you loop, ask the helper class to insert opening and closing tags if the font style has changed before writing the current character
3. At the end of the loop, ask the helper to insert the proper closing tag

I don't have an Excel interop project to play with, so here's a sample, which you may have to adapt to the specific Excel font types.

First, the helper class:

```
static class TextHelper
{
    // You may have to use a different type than `FontStyle` 
    // Hopefully ch.Font has some type of `Style` property you can use
    public static FontStyle CurrentStyle { get; set; }
    public static string OpenTag { get { return GetOpenTag(); } }
    public static string CloseTag { get { return GetCloseTag(); } }

    // This will return the closing tag for the current font style, 
    // followed by the opening tag for the new font style
    public static string ChangeStyleIfNeeded(FontStyle newStyle)
    {
        if (newStyle == CurrentStyle) return string.Empty;

        var transitionStyleTags = GetCloseTag();
        CurrentStyle = newStyle;
        transitionStyleTags += GetOpenTag();

        return transitionStyleTags;
    }

    private static string GetOpenTag()
    {
        switch (CurrentStyle)
        {
            case FontStyle.Bold:
                return "<b>";
            case FontStyle.Italic:
                return "<i>";
            case FontStyle.Underline:
                return "<u>";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    private static string GetCloseTag()
    {
        switch (CurrentStyle)
        {
            case FontStyle.Bold:
                return "</b>";
            case FontStyle.Italic:
                return "</i>";
            case FontStyle.Underline:
                return "</u>";
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Next, the implementation would look something like this:

```
// Start our helper class with 'Regular' font
TextHelper.CurrentStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
var html = new StringBuilder();

for (int index = 1; index <= cell.Text.ToString().Length; index++)
{
    char ch = cell.get_Characters(index, 1);

    // If the Font of this character is different than the current font, 
    // this will close the old style and open our new style.
    html.Append(TextHelper.ChangeStyleIfNeeded(ch.Font));

    // Append this character
    html.Append(ch.Text);
}

// Close the style at the very end
html.Append(TextHelper.CloseTag);
```

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for your great effort on my question.I modified your class little bit and its working. But my problem still no get solved. I need to retrieve bold ,italic and underlined `WORDS` one by one. Your approach gets texts in specific `FontStyle` all together as well. Same as mine.